# Read rows of different sizes into columns in python

Tags: python, rows

I have an input file that looks sort of like this:

```
0.1 0.3 0.4 0.3
0.2 02. 1.2 -0.2
0.1 -1.22 0.12 9.2 0.2 0.2
0.3 -1.42 0.2 6.2 0.9 0.88
0.3 -1.42 0.12 1.1 0.1 0.88 0.06 0.14
4
```

So it starts with some number of columns, and ends with n*2 columns (n is the last line).
I can get the number of rows, say # rows = i. I can also get n.
I want to read this file into a python 2d array (not a list), e.g. Array[i][n*2]. I realize I may need to fill the empty columns with zeros so that it can be read simply as

```
Array = numpy.loadtxt("data.txt")
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: I thought I understood what you wanted until you said `Array[i][n*2]`. That looks like a 1D array of 1D somethings. A 2D array is indexed as `a[i, j]`, and it has a shape like `(i, n*2)`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes, sorry I was confusing c++ syntax with python syntax

Comment: This isn't just a matter of syntax. C++ doesn't really have 2D arrays at all; it has arrays of arrays (and it has 1D N*M arrays that you can manually stride, of course). If you really wanted something like a C++ array of arrays, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place, because an array of arrays doesn't have to be rectangular, but a 2D array does.

Comment: Side note: you should read PEP 8: instance names are normally in lower case (`array`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any of the built-in missing-value stuff is going to help here, because space-separated columns make it ambiguous which values are missing. (Not ambiguous in your context—you know all the missing columns are on the right—but a general-purpose parser won't.) Hopefully I'm wrong and someone else will provide a simpler answer, but otherwise…

One option is to extend the lines one by one on the fly and feed them into an array. If memory isn't an issue, you can do this with a list comprehension over the row:

```
def readrow(row, cols):
    a = np.fromstring(row, sep=' ')
    a.resize((cols,)
    return a

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    a = np.array([readrow(row, 2*n) for row in f])
```

If you can't afford to waste the memory to create a temporary list of `i` 1D arrays, you may need to use something like `fromiter` to generate a 1D array, then reshape it:

```
a = np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    readrow(row, n*2) for row in f)).reshape((n*2,))
```

(Although at this point, using numpy to parse the rows instead of `csv` or just `str.split` seems like it might be a bit silly.)

Comment: I think that this is a very good answer. I can nitpick, though: `fname` is really `fpath`, and I don't understand why the `rb` mode would be necessary since the input file is obviously a text file. Thus, I would do a simple `open(fpath)`. There is also the question of the last line, which apparently contains the `n` from the original question and should not be put in the array, but let's see what Jesus says.

Comment: None of the answers here really helped. This answer looks promising but when I try to implement it, it gives error "invalid mode ('rb') or filename", which is weird since I did not include the 'rb', and I have another line with the same with open statement/file.
I have boiled it down to this: how to copy the values of a list to a numpy array that is bigger. Say list = [1 2 3 4 5] to be copied into Array[10] that has all entries zeros. How to copy the list to the first 5 elements in the array and rest leave them at zeros. Thanks

Comment: @EOL: `fname` is whatever it is in the asker's code, which he didn't give us. The `rb` mode is necessary because `np.fromstring` because in 3.x it wants `bytes`, not `str`; if you switched to `csv`, it would no longer be necessary in 3.x, but would be in 2.x. Either way, it never hurts. And the last line contains the `n` from the original question because he says he can get `i` and `n` independently, so I assume I don't need to write code that gets them.

Comment: @Jesus: Without seeing the code that's generating the error, I obviously can't help you debug it. But for your second question: sure, you _can_ create an array of 10 zeros and copy the list in, but why can't you just convert it to an array of 5 and then call `resize` on it, as in my code?

Comment: abarnert's method is good. If you want to copy to an existing NumPy array, you simply do something like `arr[:5] = range(5)` (assignment to a slice).

Comment: @abarnert: That's actually a good idea.
 I wasn't able to use the code, but I was able to use the main idea. I solved the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pad the short lines with 0.0's here is one way - pad with a full set of 0.0's, then slice only the leading significant part:

```
data = """0.1 0.3 0.4 0.3
0.2 02. 1.2 -0.2
0.1 -1.22 0.12 9.2 0.2 0.2
0.3 -1.42 0.2 6.2 0.9 0.88
0.3 -1.42 0.12 1.1 0.1 0.88 0.06 0.14
4""".splitlines()

maxcols = int(data[-1])*2

emptyvalue = 0.0
pad = [emptyvalue]*maxcols

for line in data[:-1]:
    # get the input data values, converted from strings to floats
    vals = map(float, line.split())

    # pad the input with default values, then only take the first maxcols values
    vals = (vals + pad)[:maxcols]

    # show our work in a nice table
    print "[" + ','.join("%s%.2f" % (' ' if v>=0 else '', v) for v in vals) + "]"
```

prints

```
[ 0.10, 0.30, 0.40, 0.30, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
[ 0.20, 2.00, 1.20,-0.20, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
[ 0.10,-1.22, 0.12, 9.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.00, 0.00]
[ 0.30,-1.42, 0.20, 6.20, 0.90, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00]
[ 0.30,-1.42, 0.12, 1.10, 0.10, 0.88, 0.06, 0.14]
```